# File encryption with Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, encryption

I need a file encryption program for Lubuntu v18.04.  Where can I find one? (I don't see any such program in the System Tools --> Software folder.

Answer (score 0):

From `man gpg2`:

```
NAME
       gpg2 - OpenPGP encryption and signing tool

SYNOPSIS
       gpg2 [--homedir dir] [--options file] [options] command [args]

DESCRIPTION
       gpg2  is  the OpenPGP part of the GNU Privacy Guard (GnuPG). It is a tool to provide digital encryption and signing services using the OpenPGP standard. gpg2 features
       complete key management and all bells and whistles you can expect from a decent OpenPGP implementation.
```